# Failed to install from NuGet package manager - VS 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, nuget, nuget-package

After installing vs 2022 and uninstalling it (because it doesn't support ODT - oracle developer tools).
Going back to the previous version (2017 or 2019) causes the NuGet package manager fails to install packages properly (all packages).

I've tried to install (for example) Newtonsoft.Json but it failed with the following error:

[Error Install Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jx6Vb.png)

1. I have tried to reinstall to NuGet package manager.
2. I have tried to reinstall VS (both 2017 and 2019).

Any help\ suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks, Asaf

Comment: Hi, please help to check if you meet this issue with any solutions? If you have not try to repair VS, please close the VS 2017/2019 instances and run the Visual Studio Installer as administrator, click More-Repair to repair, then test it again. How did you uninstall the VS 2017/2019 before, through Visual Studio Installer or Control Panel-Programs and Features?

Comment: I have uninstalled VS through Control Panel. I have installed VS as administrator. I found a workaround for now. I reinstalled VS 2022 along with VS 2017 and 2017 is working for now. Thanks

Comment: We are so glad to hear that your issue was solved, you can add the workaround as the Answer, that will help other community members who meet the similar issues to easier search this helpful information, thanks.